# D3.JS Attract one node by another in force simulation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, simulation, force-layout

There is an arbitrary data set, which has to be visualized by d3.forceSimulation() method.
[image]

These nodes are intractable, you can choose parent and children circles. The task is to attract children node (blue) by parent one (red), while both are chosen. And, eventually, rearrange others.

[image]

I have looked through d3.forceSimulation docs and could find any clues how to do it.

```js
//parent: red, children: blue
    
    let svg, width = 800, height = 400, radius, nodes, x, y, simulation;
    let parent = null, children = null;
    
    let data = [
      
        {id: 0, size: 0.5 },
        {id: 1, size: 0.25 },
        {id: 2, size: 0.125 },
        {id: 3, size: 0.75 },
        {id: 4, size: 0.8 },
        {id: 5, size: 0.4 },
        {id: 6, size: 0.25 },
        {id: 7, size: 0.5 }
        
    ];
    
    const tick = () => { nodes.attr("cx", d_ => d_.x ).attr("cy", d_ => d_.y ) }
    
    svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("viewBox", `0 0 ${width} ${height}`);
    
    let background = svg.append("rect").attr("width", width).attr("height", height).attr("fill", "#444444");
         
    radius = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0.0, 1.0]).range([32, 64]);
    
    x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, data.length]).range([64, width - 64]);
    y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, data.length]).range([64, height - 64]);
                
    simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("x", d3.forceX(d_ => { return x(d_.id); }).strength(0.1))
    .force("y",  d3.forceY(height / 2).strength(0.05))
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide().radius(d => radius(Number(d.size)) + 10))
    .alpha(1).restart();
    
    nodes = svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", d_ => { return radius(d_.size); })
    .attr("fill", "#FFFFFF")
    .on("mouseover", (event_, d_) => { if(parent !== d_.id && children !== d_.id) { d3.select(event_.currentTarget).attr("fill", "#888888"); } })
    .on("mouseout", (event_, d_) => { if(parent !== d_.id && children !== d_.id) { d3.select(event_.currentTarget).attr("fill", "#FFFFFF"); } })
    .on("click", (event_, d_) => {
       
        if(parent == null) { parent = d_.id; d3.select(event_.currentTarget).attr("fill", "#FF0000"); }
        else if(parent != d_.id) { 
            
            
            children = d_.id; d3.select(event_.currentTarget).attr("fill", "#0000FF");
            
            //attrackt blue node by red
            
            //...
                                 
        }
                
    });
    
    simulation.nodes(data).on("tick", tick);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It seems that I've found solution. Since all nodes are arranged by their ids, all I have to do is to rearrange indices. For example, if parent node has index 4 and child 7, all I need is to set child id as 5, and re-index 5, 6 to 6, 7.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution based on re-indexing nodes (id2).

```js
let svg, width = 800, height = 400, radius, nodes, x, y, simulation;
let parent = null, child = null;

let data = [
  
    {id: 0, id2: 0, size: 0.5 },
    {id: 1, id2: 1, size: 0.25 },
    {id: 2, id2: 2, size: 0.125 },
    {id: 3, id2: 3,  size: 0.75 },
    {id: 4, id2: 4,  size: 0.8 },
    {id: 5, id2: 5,  size: 0.4 },
    {id: 6, id2: 6,  size: 0.25 },
    {id: 7, id2: 7,  size: 0.5 }
    
];

const tick = () => { nodes.attr("transform", d_ => `translate(${d_.x},${d_.y})`); } //nodes.attr("cx", d_ => d_.x ).attr("cy", d_ => d_.y ) }

const attract = () => {
    
    let element = data[child];
    data.splice(child, 1);
    
    if(child > parent) { data.splice(parent + 1, 0, element); } else { data.splice(parent - 1, 0, element); }
    
    data.forEach((d_, i_) => { d_.id2 = i_; })
    
    parent = null; child = null;
    d3.selectAll("circle").attr("fill", "#FFFFFF");
    
    simulation.force("x", d3.forceX(d_ => { return x(d_.id2); }).strength(0.2))
    .force("y",  d3.forceY(height / 2).strength(0.05))
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide().radius(d => radius(Number(d.size)) + 10))
    .alpha(1).restart();

}

svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("viewBox", `0 0 ${width} ${height}`);

let background = svg.append("rect").attr("width", width).attr("height", height).attr("fill", "#444444");
     
radius = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0.0, 1.0]).range([32, 64]);

x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, data.length]).range([64, width - 64]);
y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, data.length]).range([64, height - 64]);
            
simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
.force("x", d3.forceX(d_ => { return x(d_.id2); }).strength(0.2))
.force("y",  d3.forceY(height / 2).strength(0.05))
.force("collide", d3.forceCollide().radius(d => radius(Number(d.size)) + 10))
.alpha(1).restart();

nodes = svg.selectAll(null)
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("g");

nodes.append("circle")
.attr("id", d_ => "node_" + d_.id)
.attr("r", d_ => { return radius(d_.size); })
.attr("fill", "#FFFFFF")
.on("mouseover", (event_, d_) => { if(parent !== d_.id2 && child !== d_.id2) { d3.select(event_.currentTarget).attr("fill", "#888888"); } })
.on("mouseout", (event_, d_) => { if(parent !== d_.id2 && child !== d_.id2) { d3.select(event_.currentTarget).attr("fill", "#FFFFFF"); } })
.on("click", (event_, d_) => {
   
    if(parent == null) { parent = d_.id2; d3.select(event_.currentTarget).attr("fill", "#FF0000"); }
    
    else if(parent != d_.id2) { 
        
        child = d_.id2; d3.select(event_.currentTarget).attr("fill", "#0000FF");
        
        attract();
                             
    }
            
});

nodes.append("text").attr("class", "non-selectable").attr("text-anchor", "middle").attr("alignment-baseline", "middle").text(d_ => d_.id);

simulation.nodes(data).on("tick", tick);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
```